# How to give an alias name with a space in sparksql

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

i have tried below codes

trial-1

..........

```
val df2=sqlContext.sql("select concat(' ',Id,LabelName) as 'first last'  from  p1 order by LabelName desc ");
```

trial-2

.........

```
val df2=sqlContext.sql("select concat(' ',Id,LabelName)   from  p1 order by LabelName desc ");

val df3=df2.toDF("first last")
```

trial-1 is throwing error when i tried to run it.......but in trial-2 it is taking the command but throwing the error when i performed below action

```
scala> df3.write.parquet("/prashanth/a1")
```

Comment: I happened to know these errors. But next time please paste the stack trace of errors. Most of people can tell you why it failed without trying to reproduce it by themselves.

Answer (score 8):

1. When a SQL column contains special characters in a SQL statement, you can use `` ` ``, such as `` `first last` ``.
2. You cannot use `space` in a Parquet column. You can either rename the column or use other file format, such as `csv`.